# using counter to prevent long coding

Tags: android, counter

I've been searching for a while to help me with my question, but couldn't find any good tutorials. I started Android recently, so I'm not that good jet. My question is how I can convert my code in a way that I don't have to type everything. I was thinking maybe to use a counter. I want to know if there is a possibility that I only have to set the visibility of the seekbar and the button once. This is my code:

```
private void numberPlayers() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("rbPlayers");
    if (str.equals("rb2")) {
        sbPlayer3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (str.equals("rb3")) {
        sbPlayer4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (str.equals("rb4")) {
        sbPlayer5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sbPlayer6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (str.equals("rb5")) {
        sbPlayer6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bPlus6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can at first set all your element visibility to Gone and after that in if condition set the visibility of your goal element to visible. also this is good for such code above .

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to Android, but I would suggest the following approach:

Hold all your variables (such as `sbPlayer5` or `bPlus6`) in an array - you can use `ArrayList` to hold any type of object and have the array grow automatically. So you can access the correct object by a numeric index.

Pass `rbPlayers` as an `Integer` instead of `String`.

Then iterate over your array using the numeric index (`for`) and call `setVisibility` inside the loop for all indexes above your maximum.

Answer (score 1):

- If your layout elements are contained in each other then you can call the method on the parent one and it will call the same method on its children.
- If your objects all inherit from the same base class you can put them in arrays and use a cycle to iterate through them and call the method.

Comment: Thank you! I'll search for a tutorial that can help me further. Maybe you know a good one?

Comment: Tutorial on what? If you mean Android, the starting poin is http://developer.android.com/index.html#. Here you can find the basics of all you need to know.